# Custom notification bar hiding the image when it is clicked

Tags: android, notifications

I am making a Radio like app in Android, in which I need to show the current playing channel in the notification bar with "Play/Pause" buttons. so what i need to do is that when user click on pause button song should be paused and play image should be displayed. I have done doing pause for sound from notification bar but now i need to show the play image instead of pause image, and i also need to put the seek bar to control the volume for music. Thanks in advance.
[image: This is how i want to show play/pause images in between next/previous images.]

Comment: You need to re-publish the notification. Reconstruct the `RemoteViews` using the play button image instead of pause button image and then call `startForeground` again from your service.

Comment: can you tell me how i can re-publish it ?

Comment: I just did: "call `startForeground` again from your service"

Comment: can you please show me code to show how you actually did ? or can you send me code on deeplove9493@gmail.com

Comment: ...Are you using a foreground service?

Comment: i don't know what is Foreground service.

Answer (score 0):

To update a notification, you simply call `notificationManager.notify()` again and pass it the same `id` that you gave it last time. if there's an existing notification with that `id`, it will update that one with the new information.

Typically for music playback or other persistent behaviors that the user should have control over, a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) is used. You use a regular Service and call `startForeground()`, passing it an id and a notification just like you would for `NotificationManager`. The benefit of this approach is that Android is less likely to terminate your service if it starts looking for processes to clean up as long as your service is running in the foreground. Updating the notification works the same way: call `startForeground()` again with the same `id` and a new notification object.